# Looking for an in-app in-memory filesystem in C/C++

Tags: library, c++, c, filesystems

I'm looking for an in-memory in-app filesystem that I can use as a library from a C program. Ideally should be POSIX compatible.

What I have found so far:

- Zbox [here](https://github.com/zboxfs/zbox-c) is a possible solution for what I'm looking for, but has some encryption overhead that I want to avoid.
- Another possible venue is [this](https://github.com/yyzybb537/memfs) implementation that I can copy-paste from a project that targets FUSE, but it is unmaintained.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Recent linuxes support per-process mount namespaces. I.e. you can mount a tmpfs/ramfs on a way which is visible only for your process. Possibly it can be done even without root.